# How to add custom directory to Scala SBT project?

Tags: scala, sbt

We have `conf` directory in our project which is fine, but one of the new components requires its own config to be placed into `config` directory and we can't change that requirement. In my build.scala I added the line:

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "config",
```

In SBT when I run `$ inspect tree package-src` I can see the `config` directory under `compile:unmanagedResourceDirectories` section which is under `compile:packageSrc::mappings` section.

Then I try to check the deployment package locally by running `$ publishLocal`. The target `config` directory is missing in the result .zip package.

What did I miss / do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I added to my Build.scala to finally solve the issue:

```
mappings in Universal ++= (baseDirectory.value / "config" * "*" get) map
  (x => x -> ("config/" + x.getName)),
```