# Add custom folder to SBT build package

Tags: java, scala, sbt, playframework-2.0

I am trying to add custom folder called **clients** to a build package. Therefore i could override my default configuration or other resources but i am not able to add it. I have tried couple of solutions though which is give on [How to add custom directory to Scala SBT project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33348422/how-to-add-custom-directory-to-scala-sbt-project).

[image: folder structure]

Answer (score 0):

Try using mappings, it should work follow the method specified in following link http://www.codepreference.com/2016/05/adding-distribution-folder-play-application.html